# How to verify the results of DSolve that contain `RootSum`?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

This question arised from [Chini Equations](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DSolveChiniEquations).

In:

```
DSolve[y'[x] == 5*y[x]^4 + 3*x^(-4/3), y[x], x]
```

Out:
$\text{Solve}\left[-45 \text{RootSum}\left[-45 \text{$\#$1}^4+\sqrt[4]{3} 5^{3/4} \text{$\#$1}-45\&,\frac{\log \left(\sqrt[4]{\frac{5}{3}} \sqrt[4]{x^{4/3}} y(x)-\text{$\#$1}\right)}{\sqrt[4]{3} 5^{3/4}-180 \text{$\#$1}^3}\&\right]=c_1+\frac{3^{3/4} \sqrt[4]{5} x \log (x)}{\left(x^{4/3}\right)^{3/4}},y(x)\right]$

Grateful for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use implicit differentiation:

```
res = DSolve[y'[x] == 5*y[x]^4 + 3*x^(-4/3), y[x], x];
eqn = First[res];

Solve[D[eqn, x], y'[x]] // Simplify
```

> ```
> {{y'[x] -> 3x^(-4/3) + (-1/(3x) - 1/(3x^(4/3)^(3/4)))y[x] + 5y[x]^4}}
> ```

The answer seems to not quite work since `-1/(3x) - 1/(3x^(4/3)^(3/4))` is never zero. Looks like a branch cut issue.

Consider using this solution instead:

```
eqn = RootSum[9 + #1 + 15#1^4 &, 
  Log[-#1 + x^(1/3)y[x]]/(1 + 60#1^3) &] == Log[x^(1/3)] + C[1];

Solve[D[eqn, x], y'[x]] // Simplify
```

> ```
> {{y'[x] -> 3x^(-4/3) + 5y[x]^4}}
> ```

Comment: To be frank, in order to practice using Wolfram Language, I'm writing some code that **automatically verify** (prefer symbolic to numeric) the solution of `DSolve`. But now for this question, I can't even see how you got `RootSum[9 + #1 + 15#1^4 &, Log[-#1 + x^(1/3)y[x]]/(1 + 60#1^3) &] == Log[x^(1/3)] + C[1]`, although your answer is very close to what I want. So please show me the code that do the transformation automatically, thanks!

Comment: I just slightly tweaked the output of the step-by-step solution on Wolfram|Alpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%5Bx%5D+%3D%3D+5*y%5Bx%5D%5E4+%2B+3*x%5E(-4%2F3)

Comment: @ooo You can use the Mathematica `WolframAlpha[“y’[x] == 5*y[x]^4 + 3*x^(-4/3)”]` to see all the steps. I then evaluated the final integral in its indefinite form and simplified slightly. If you have issues, let me know.

Comment: @ooo but I will say the method I posted in my answer is a way to verify an implicit solution to an ode. I think in this case the solution provided by `Dsolve` is slightly wrong.

Comment: Step-by-step solution gives the answer: $\int_1^{\sqrt[3]{x}y(x)} \frac3{15 u^4+u+9} \, du = \log(x)+c_1$ 1. Why the definite form can't be calculated efficiently whereas the indefinite form can be? **2. Can you write code that *automates* all of these things (extraction and transformation)?** — this is the ultimate goal of the post too. ;)

Comment: @ooo Definite integrals are harder because continuity of the antiderivative needs to be examined. It gets tricky when there are parameters involved. See http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/01/19/mathematica-and-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus/. As for your other comment, my original post *is* the way to automate this. You should be able to just use implicit differentiation to verify if an equation is a solution to an ODE or not.

Comment: But how to deal with the "redundant" term - y[x] automatically (and "generally")? Directly substituting back won't get right... Could it be right for any case if we just simply drop the y[x]?

Comment: @ooo my approach is correct. I think the output from `DSolve` is slightly wrong in this case. It should work for other implicit solutions given by `DSolve`.

Answer (score 3):

here is a first stab at looking at this numerically:

```
sol = DSolve[y'[x] == 5*y[x]^4 + 3*x^(-4/3), y[x], x]
```

find the `C[1]` constant for some particular initial condition:

```
c = Solve[sol[[1]] /. {y[x] -> 0, x -> 1}, C[1]][[1, 1]]
```

then use findroot to generate solution:

```
ysol[xarg_] := 
 Chop[z /. FindRoot[sol[[1]] /. c /. {y[x] -> z, x -> xarg} , {z, 0}]]
```

compare with numerical solution to the original equation:

```
nsol[xarg_] = 
       NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == 5*y[x]^4 + 3*x^(-4/3), y[1] == 0}, 
         y[x], {x, .8, 1.4}] /. x -> xarg

Plot[{ysol[xx], nsol[xx]}, {xx, .8, 1.4}]
```

[image]

not exactly the same but I expect if you play around with precision they will converge.  Note both solutions become unstable outside the range shown.